# CSS variable receiving a value from SASS function

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

Is there a way to assign a value from a SASS function on a CSS variable?

I tried different things like:

`--color: lighten(blue, 10%);   // from a simple color`

`--color: lighten(var(--blue), 10%);   // from another CSS variable`

`--color: lighten(#{$blue}, 10%);   // from a SASS variable`

`--color: #{lighten(blue, 10%)};   // all function inside an interpolation`

Nothing works.

Thanks.

Comment: the last one works fine

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It works with:

`--color: #{lighten(blue, 10%)};`

or

`--color: #{lighten($blue, 10%)};`